# Puppeteer - Can't click on elements randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have an array of elements. I want each time to click on another element in the array. How do I do that? It's important for me to emphasize that `style[0]` must not be changed. I want to access element in another location for example: `element[0]` etc. Thanks for the help.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".pioscnbf")]
    .find(element => element.style[0].includes("background-image"))?.click();
});
```

I WANT TO CLICK ON `ELEMENT[0]`... `ELEMENT[1]`... randomly...

Please help me,
I want to click on this background of facebook:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the random elements can sometimes be repeated, this can suffice:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".pioscnbf")]
    .filter(element => element.style[0].includes("background-image"));

  if (elements.length) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
    elements[randomIndex].click();
  }
});
```

Otherwise, you can return the index of the clicked element, store it in an array and transfer this array to the next evaluated functions to exclude these elements.